# How can I do a double delimiter in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

let's say I have some sample rows of data

```
site1^http://article1.com?datacoll=5|4|3|2|1&test=yes
site1^http://article1.com?test=yes
site1^http://article1.com?datacoll=5|4|3|2|1&test=yes
```

I want to create a table like so
create table clicklogs (sitename string, url string) 
ROW format delimited fields terminated by '^';

As you can see I have some data in the url parameter I'd like to extract, namely
datacoll=5|4|3|2|1

I also want to work with those individual elements seperated by pipes so I can do group bys on them to show for example how many urls had a 2nd position of "4" which would be 2 rows in this case. So in this case I have the "url" field that has additional data I'd like to parse out and use in my queries.

The question is, what is the best way to do that in hive?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `parse_url(string urlString, string partToExtract [, string keyToExtract])` to grab the data in question:

```
parse_url('http://article1.com?datacoll=5|4|3|2|1&test=yes', 'QUERY', 'datacol1')
```

This returns `'5|4|3|2|1'`, which gets us halfway there. Now, use `split(string str, string pat)` to break those out of each sub-delimiter into an array:

```
split(parse_url(url, 'QUERY', 'datacol1'), '\|')
```

With the result of this, you should be able to grab the columns that you want.

See [the UDF documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) for more built-in functions.

Note: I wasn't able to verify this works in Hive from where I am, sorry if there are some minor issues.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very similar to something I've done a couple weeks ago, I think the best approach in your case would be to apply a pre-processing step (possibly with hadoop streaming), and change the prototype of your table to be:

```
create table clicklogs(sitename string, datacol Array<int>) row format delimited fields terminated by '^' collection items terminated by '|'
```

Once you have that you can easily manipulate your data in Hive using lateral views and the builtin `explode`. The following code should help you get the counts of URLs per col.

```
select col, count(1) from clicklogs lateral view explode(datacol) dataTable as col group by col
```